# Ajaxcontrol toolkit: Combobox: list moves when zooming or scrolling on mobile

Tags: mobile, combobox, scroll, zooming, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When putting a combox in our webapplication, it works great with pc browsers. 
However when i try to use it with a mobile (tested with android and IOS) the location of the combobox moves when i zoom or scroll through the page.

It seems the list is not fixed tot the control.

my code:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptmanager" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:comboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" 
    DropDownStyle="DropDownlist" 
    AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
    CaseSensitive="false"
    RenderMode="block"
    ItemInsertLocation="Append"
    ListItemHoverCssClass="ComboBoxListItemHover">
      <asp:ListItem>test</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem> 

    </asp:comboBox>
```

in CSS i've also put: 
        .ajax__combobox_itemlist{
        position: fixed !important;
        } 
this fixes the fact that the list starts at the wrong place